# How to make coroutines run in order?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is using Unity3D. I have three coroutines: `GetJSONFromSelectedSubreddit()`, `LoadMoreMemes()`, and a function in a separate script that needs to be able to access the array of memes through the `GetNewMemes()` function (must return type Meme[]). `LoadNewMemes()` produces. The thing is, `LoadMoreMemes()` requires the json to work, so they have to run in the mentioned order. If you need the functions, here they are:

```
public void GetNewMemes(string subReddit, int count)
{
    SetSelectedSubreddit(subReddit);
    memesAtATime = count;
    subJSON = null;
    StartCoroutine(GetJSONFromSelectedSubreddit());
    StartCoroutine(LoadMoreMemes());
}

IEnumerator GetJSONFromSelectedSubreddit()
{
    gettingJSON = true;
    WWW requester = new WWW("https://www.reddit.com/r/" + selectedSub + "/new.json?sort=new&count=25&after=" + postIndex);
    yield return requester;
    subJSON = requester.text;
    json = new JSONObject(subJSON);
    gettingJSON = false;
}

IEnumerator LoadMoreMemes()
{
    while (gettingJSON)
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
    for (int i = 0; i < memesAtATime; i++)
    {
        yield return StartCoroutine(GetUserPostKarma(json["data"]["children"][i]["data"]["author"].str));

        string sourceURL = json["data"]["children"][i]["data"]["preview"]["images"][0]["source"]["url"].str;
        sourceURL = sourceURL.Replace("&amp;", "&");

        yield return StartCoroutine(GrabImage(sourceURL));

        Meme currentMeme = new Meme(
                json["data"]["children"][i]["data"]["preview"]["images"][0]["source"]["url"].str,
                authorPostKarma,
                (int) json["data"]["children"][i]["data"]["score"].i,
                json["data"]["children"][i]["data"]["permalink"].str,
                json["data"]["children"][i]["data"]["title"].str,
                currentBitmap
        );
        Debug.Log(currentMeme.cost);
        memes[i] = currentMeme;
    }
}
```

Here's the other script:

```
void Start ()
{
    RedditCommunicator redditCommunicator = GetComponent<RedditCommunicator>();
    redditCommunicator.GetNewMemes("me_irl", 1);
    Meme[] memes = redditCommunicator.GetCurrentMemes();
    Debug.Log(memes[0].currentScore);
    redditCommunicator.SpawnOneMeme(memes[0]);
}
```

Each function works fine on its own, but they need to wait for each other to finish, as well as run in the correct order to work. I'd like the functions to stay separate so I can call them individually in the future. `memes` is a private variable, and the one I'd like to pass to the other script calling these functions. If you don't think I've tried my options Googling and solving this on my own, just believe me, I've done my best. Thanks for your help in advance. If you need more information, just ask me for it. The current state of this code is it returns memes to early, before the coroutines can finish, resulting in empty memes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can yield a Coroutine in an IEnumerator which will halt the progression of that Coroutine until that Coroutine is done. Like this:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(DoThings((text) => {
        Debug.Log("Dothings told me: " + text);
    }));
}

IEnumerator DoThings(Action<string>() callback)
{
    yield return StartCoroutine(DoThisFirst());
    callback("Returning a value mid-method!");
    yield return StartCoroutine(ThenThis());
    Debug.Log(3);
}

IEnumerator DoThisFirst()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    Debug.Log(1);
}

IEnumerator ThenThis()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    Debug.Log(2);
}
```

Comment: The function that I call will return a value before DoThings is completed. I would have to make it return void, and have the enumerator set a public variable, and get it from the other script. I'd rather not do this but if that's what I have to do....

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand but I'll update the post to show you how to implement a callback.

Answer (score -1):

Problem is that `GetJSONFromSelectedSubreddit` and `LoadNewMemes` methods are called as two "parallel" coroutines in `GetNewMemes` method.

If you do not need to run a coroutine "asynchronously", you can just enumerate through it:

```
public void GetNewMemes(string subReddit, int count)
{
    SetSelectedSubreddit(subReddit);
    memesAtATime = count;
    subJSON = null;

    var enumerator = GetJSONFromSelectedSubreddit();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext());

    enumerator = LoadNewMemes();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext());
}
```

Comment: Coroutines are NOT async.