# How can i prevent coroutines from bloating my class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

Im a bit annoyed with having two methods everytime i need something to be done by a coroutine. I need the coroutine and another method to start the coroutine. That is, i need some code to be executed only when previous code is finished.

I wanted to solve it by starting a anonymous method as coroutine but I've learned it doesn't work. Is there any other tip or trick out there on how to avoid getting your class bloated with extra methods because of a need of coroutine?

Comment: Could you please explain it with some code?

Answer (score 2):

So... If I'm understanding this correct, you want code that executes a method that starts a coroutine, but you don't want to bloat your code with the 1:1 relation of a specific method to start each specific coroutine.

And you don't want to use the "StartCoroutine" in your main code? If bloating code is what you want to avoid, you can do this, which is similar to the three method solution but uses the same method to Start every coroutine.

```
void Start()
{
    _(DoThings("Hello"));
    _(DoAnotherThing(" world!"));
}

void _(IEnumerator Method)
{
    StartCoroutine(Method);
}

IEnumerator DoThings(string value)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    Debug.Log(value);
}

IEnumerator DoAnotherThing(string value)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    Debug.Log(value);
}
```

Comment: I was to give that answer as well and then realized the fact that it does not bring any value if you want to expose some public functionalities. You got it all private there so fine. But if it were to be public then you'd have to make it all public and the usage of _ is no longer useful as you can call the coroutine directly. And I assume, he meant to have a  public call.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do what @Fredrik illustrates in his answer (which is equivalent to using `StartCoroutine` but just encapsulates it in a different method), if you're looking to avoid `StartCoroutine` littering your code. This helps keep the method count down even if you are doing this for an API that may be called from a class that doesn't inherit `MonoBehaviour` and can't call `StartCoroutine`.

As for

> That is, i need some code to be executed only when previous code is finished.

I use a callback approach in coroutines, which looks like the following:

```
IEnumerator Coroutine1(Action callback) {
    // Contents of coroutine

    callback();
}
```

Which is utilized as follows:

```
StartCoroutine(Coroutine1(() => StartCoroutine(Coroutine2())));
```

Comment: That's a neat way of doing it, never thought of it like that. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42686123/how-to-make-coroutines-run-in-order) is how I usually do it, but your solution definitely has some perks in some cases! Nice

Comment: You can even return directly an `IEnumerator` to decrease overhead. Like this: `IEnumerator Task1() { yield return Task2(); } IEnumerator Task2() { yield return Task3(); }` etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my sample method_01 .

```
public void HandleMethod() { 
    StartCoroutine (Method_01 ());
}

private IEnumerator Method_01() {
    var count = 5;
    var wait1Second = new WaitForSeconds (1f); // wait
    Debug.Log ("Start method 1");
    while (count > 0) {
        Debug.Log (count);
        yield return wait1Second;     // Each second
    }
    Debug.Log ("End method 1");
    yield return null;
    Debug.Log ("Start method 2");
    yield return wait1Second;
    Debug.Log ("End method 2");
}
```

Comment: Yes so this requires three different methods. The only reason for the different methods is to get the the code to execute in the correct order. So i was thinking if there is a way to do it in one method.

Comment: Sure :D i edited.

Comment: thats better. I do that too. But i would like to be able to do it all in the first method. I know it cant be done with anonymous functions.

Comment: Done :D. The start method can be IEnumerator .... I think it right :D

Comment: Yes i think so too. but what if you want to do it somewhere else?

Comment: OK it need more improve but i think ... it done :D

Comment: Im thankfull for your attention but now you have three methods. :D

Comment: Sometime ..... i ..... forgot .... remove .... something .. :D

Comment: Ok. So now You are back to Two methods. I Wanted One. :)

Comment: How about a class if i create a class and write only one method ?? .. I don't think Lambda or Delegate work in this case. :D So ... HOOW ? i think i can use Thread and Delegate to solve case "ONE METHOD" not sure about Thread not work on background.....